# How can I get the avatar or other extra_data using django-social-auth?

Tags: django, facebook, django-socialauth

I'm using django-social-auth to integrate with Facebook, but I don't know how's the best way to get the extra_data values on template.

Looks like a dumb question, but I need some help.

Best Regards,
Max

Comment: it is fully documented: https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/docs/backends/facebook.rst   the way is: `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email', 'user_birthday']` Here a discussion for avatar: https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/39

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use django-allauth[1], and it's very **very** good, solved my problem, like a charm.

[1]https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth